# installing mongoose on windows

Tags: windows, node.js, mongoose, npm

I am trying to install mongoose on a windows 7 machine by

```
npm install mongoose
```

but cant get it to work.
the error is:

```
kerberos.vcxproj -> D:\dan\revert\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\build\Release\\kerberos.node

> bson-ext@0.1.6 install D:\dan\revert\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext
> ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp.js install --fallback-to-build

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bson-ext@0.1.6
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package mongoose does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer node-restful@0.1.18 wants mongoose@~3

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "mongoose"
npm ERR! cwd D:\dan\revert
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.34
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I tried:

1. npm install -g node-gyp
2. npm uninstall mongodb --save
   npm install mongoose --save

Any idea will be welcome

Comment: I see the note "node -v v0.10.34" Installing mongoose works for me but I'm running node 0.12.2. Possibly a mismatch between mongoose and node?

Comment: I also see "wants mongoose@~3" whereas `npm view mongoose versions` shows the latest version of Mongoose is 4.0. you may wish to install Mongoose 3.8 or so.

Answer (score 1):

I would have left a comment, but I don't have enough reputation points.

I agree with @user645715, try a lower version of mongoose.  Or install the latest node & npm. Look into Node Version Manager (NVM) for easy switching between versions of node.

On windows to get node-gyp to build you need to install Python 2.7 and have the visual studio build components.  Just install Visual Studio Express.  This is all in the node-gyp documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save mongoose@3.8.35
```